# Simple text gets underlined and clickable in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am using Notepad++ v6.7.9.2. I have created a file and then reopened that file to add some extra text. Now when I add more text into the file, the newly added text gets underlined and also becomes clickable (just like a hyperlink).

I have tried this option **Settings > Preferences > Misc** and toggle the options under **Clickable link settting**. But doing this affects the whole document.

How do I change and stop this underlined clickable text option?

Comment: Can you tell us what the text is that got hyperlinked?

Comment: There is simple text that I'm entering with my bare hands.

Comment: and WHAT exactly is the text? if you want us to help you, we need more information.

Comment: "A better, albeit more complex approach to fluid images is to measure the width of the image as a percentage of the overall width of the page.

For example, let’s say you had an image that had a natural size of 500px × 300px in a 1200px wide document. Below 1200px, the document will be fluid. The calculation of how much width the image takes up as a percentage of the document is easy: (500 / 1200 ) × 100 = 41.66% "  this is the text I am entering.

Comment: Just copied the text and pasted it in my notepad++ and it doesn't create a hyperlink, not even after I reopen the text. Can you perhaps post a screenshot of what it looks like?

Comment: it is just happened with only one file. Creating new file or any other existing file does not have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just solve my problem by cutting all newly added text and paste into new file. Then again copy and paste in previous file got no issue.

Comment: You can just cut and paste in the same file and it would go away. :)